# ¿Como crear un boton de cerrar en una activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragment

Hola quiero crear un botón de cerrar en una toolbar de una activity para que al pulsarlo me devuelva al fragment anterior, pero no me funciona. Este es el codigo de la activity:

```
class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)

        //Establecer Menu de Arriba
        EPToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.edit_profile_menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.closeEP -> {
                finish()
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

}
```

Comment: primero haz un onBackPressed y luego el finish

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
//método que crea el menú
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
//método que registra el item pulsado del menú
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    //se declara vairable entera para la posición del item
    int id = item.getItemId();
    int pos;
    //en función del item del menú pulsado
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        //si escoge la primera opción del menú
        case R.id.opcion1:
            //espacio para programar lo que ocurre con ésta pulsación
            break;
        case R.id.opcion2:
            //espacio reservado para programar lo que secede tras ésta eleción
            break;
        case R.id.opcion3:
            //si elegimos ésta opción cerramos la activity
            finish();
            break;
    }
    //se retorna el item seleccionado
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

el xml del menú

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- primera opción del menú -->
    <item android:id="@+id/opcion1"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="Parte 1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <!-- segunda opción del menú -->
    <item android:id="@+id/opcion2"
        android:title="Parte 2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <!-- tercera opción del menú -->
    <item android:id="@+id/opcion3"
        android:title="Cerrar"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```